# What's the verb for "color commentator"?

Tags: word-request

What's the verb for "color commentator"? What verb do you use to say that a color commentator is commenting on a sports game? Sometimes, I want to avoid using the word "color commentator" and I want to use the verb variant of the term "color commenting" or "color commentator".

Comment: Can you give us an example sentence in which you'd use this?

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a dictionary defined verb for this, but "**provide colour**" is commonly used.

Answer (score 0):

I'd never heard the term "color commentator" but it seems to be typically an ex-player who gives expert analysis on the game. So you could call them an analyst, or a pundit

So you would say that the color commentator is *analysing* the game.

> Today I'll be joined by former Penguins player, Rick Martindale, who'll be *analysing* the game and *offering insights* based on his 20 years as a player and a coach.

At any given time the color commentator could also be summarising the play, reflecting on the performances or just cracking a joke.

Answer (score 0):

In the U.S., we often say that someone "provides" color commentary. There is no verb form. (I.e., you can't say that someone "color comments".)

You could also say that someone "analyzes" or "comments on" a game, but those terms are not as specific.

Answer (score 0):

The *color commentator* provides **commentary** on the game as opposed to analysis.  The CC will tell you the quarterback's wife, Melinda, just gave birth to their second set of twins.   The analyst will tell you the last time his wife gave birth he was 22 for 22 in passing.

In practice, most sports announcers provide both color commentary and analysis.